# Python - pandas converts MS SQL date to nvarchar

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

My python code runs `read_sql...` method on a sample MS SQL Server query.

One of the columns - `system_type_name` - indicates type `date` while running in SSMS.

[image]

Query executed with below code gives me `nvarchar(10)` type:

Config.json:

```
{"Drive": "SQL Server",
 "Server": "server_name",
 "Database":......
 "UID":........
 "PWD":......}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

query = '''
    DECLARE @dt
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'procedure_name 0, ''1900-01-01'', @dt';
    SELECT system_type_name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0) '''


cnxn = connect_to_db("config.json", False)
src = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
print(src)
```

df result:

```
                  num_legs
system_type_name  nvarchar(10)
```

Is this some conversion bug/issue pandas is having with `date` type?

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: It's in the post - `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0)`

Comment: Regarding my answer (now deleted).  It was me not understanding your question.... Terribly sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No problem! Good we came to same conclusion ;)

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using? "SQL Server"? "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"? Something else?

Comment: And what is the Stored Procedure definition?

Comment: `"Drive": "SQL Server"`

Comment: Definition is a simple SQL query only

Comment: Changing to `"Driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"` fixed the issue. Why is that?

Comment: IMO you should probably just use [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-for-object-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and pass it the name of the procedure, there is no need for the dynamic SQL

Comment: I hear you but going into details why it is arranged this way would become a seperate topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ancient "SQL Server" driver returns a string representation for several T-SQL types. Newer ODBC drivers return more specific types. For example:

```py
# with DRIVER=SQL Server
#
print(type(crsr.execute("SELECT CAST('2022-01-17' AS DATE) AS d").fetchval()))
# <class 'str'>

# with DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
#
print(type(crsr.execute("SELECT CAST('2022-01-17' AS DATE) AS d").fetchval()))
# <class 'datetime.date'>
```